# Правильно ли все написано?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография

На этом канале ежедневно постятся ссылки, перейдя по каким и выполнив не сложные задания можно получить платные игры в Стиме бесплатно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

Верно:

> На этом канале ежедневно **публикуются** (лучше; либо *постятся*) ссылки, перейдя по которым и выполнив **нес**ложные задания, *(запятая!)* можно бесплатно получить платные игры **из** **«Стима»**.

Answer (score 0):

*Поститься* — соблюдать пост. Слово *пост* в смысле сообщения, помещенного в интернетовских соцсетях, прочно вошло в молодежный сленг, но "*поститься*" в  смысле "быть помещенным в виде поста в соцсетях" - это звучит, на мой взгляд, слишком уж новаторски. А в остальном — см. ответ *Aer*.